# Why does Doctrine and Oracle not respect equality in strings?

Tags: oracle, symfony, doctrine

I have a weird case. I am running a Symfony application with an Oracle 11 database connected using Doctrine.

My problem is that when I run this two different queries:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = 'charles.robinson@email.com'
SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = 'charlesrobinson@email.com'
```

I get the same result, a record with the `charles.robinson@email.com` user. It seems that neither Oracle or Doctrine are aware of the dot.

Since I don't have direct access to the database I am running them using the command:

```
php bin/console doctrine:query:sql
```

Comment: I think that its not the bug, because, for example  in gmail charles.robinson@email.com = charlesrobinson@email.com, email providers are ignoring dot, its just visual separator

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with the configuration on the ORACLE side. The NLS_COMP value allowed this kind of results.